# How may I prevent the Designer changing control member modifiers to private?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

When in the Designer I change a property of a DataGridViewColumn on which I previously manually changed the modifier to **public** in the .Designer.cs file, the modifier gets reverted to **private**.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend not changing the designer.

If you really need to have your controls public, I would recommend adding a property to expose them in your code file (not the designer file):

```
public TextBox MyTextBox { get { return this.textBox1; } }
```

This will provide public access to the designer generated types without worry of the designer overwriting your changes.

It also makes it much more clear, in the long run, since your public API is defined in your main code file, and not in a second, designer generated file.

That being said, in general, I'd avoid this.  Instead of exposing the control itself, I would actually recommend exposing the *data* that you want to set.  Take the text box above - If this text box was a title, I would expose that directly:

```
public string Title
{  
    get { return this.textBoxTitle.Text; }
    set { this.textBoxTitle.Text = value; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Reed, but having to manually add a property for each control member I need to access, each time I add a control in the Designer, is something I would like to avoid. Hence my use of **public**.

Comment: @ChrisJJ: That's part of my point - the control details should be internal, and not public.  Focus on putting in the properties for your type that are important to the outside world - that can be a single class that gets set, even, and maps to all of the controls...

Comment: How would you avoid having to manually add a property for each control member I need to access, each time I add a control in the Designer?

Comment: @ChrisJJ: I wouldn't - I would keep the public surface as small as possible, but would want to add a member and control it.